# Mapping complex JSON resttemplate

Tags: java, json, jackson, resttemplate

I am trying to get response back from a rest service using rest template.

The structure of JSON looks like this:

Here is the code I have implemented;

Comment: Have you tried using `Data[]` instead of `List<Data>` in your `Response` class? IIRC there is not type information left about the `List` interface at runtime, even when using reflection

Comment: yes, I have tried that also. Stll no luck!

Comment: is it possible for you to change your JSON data i.e. make like `[{
        "ResponseType": "SUCCESS",
        "transaction_id": "66429961-3dfa-4e76-8216-293106c7b369",
        "Data": [
            {
                "incident_id": "3232312",
                "external_reference_id": "0",
                "incident_url": "https://url"
            }
        ],
        "Version": "0.0.1",
        "InvokingUser": "unknown",
        "Duration": 1658,
        "RequestAt": "2018-04-04T20:03:48.200Z"
    }]`

Comment: also you can try defining your list as `@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
 private List<Data> data;`

Comment: try to run `String rawResponse = template.postForObject(staging, obj.toString(), String.class);` and make sure that produced json is in expected format

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I tried doing that but response not capturing the Data object fields..I need those fields!

Comment: @RamKumar try to put `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on Data class

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko Thanks a lot for your help! Issue has been resolved. :)